# Implementing open-source Ruby modules in .liquid?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, shopify, liquid

I am developing an online store for a customer. This is my first attempt at using Shopify. The customer has requested that products be listed with a price in words instead of numbers (ex. "$19.00" shows as "nineteen dollars).

I have located an open-source module called [humanize](https://github.com/radar/humanize) which will accomplish what I would like. My question now is, how can I implement this in my Shopify site?

Thanks
Tbg

Comment: I don't think Shopify lets you run arbitrary Ruby code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only hope on this is to setup an App for yourself, with an App Proxy endpoint.

You will be able to then make a secure Ajax call with the amount ($19) and pass that to humanize running in that App. You just return the result as the response.

So your Shopify store may take a split second or two, but you can replace the $19 with nineteen that way for sure.